# aiohttp asyncio parsing works fine for a time, then without any error gets no data

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I need to parse html from list of domains (only main pages)

Script works well for a period of time, then it's getting no data with very high speed. Looks like requests doesn't even send.

My code:

```
import asyncio
import time
import aiohttp
import pandas as pd
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

df = pd.read_excel('work_file.xlsx')
domains_count = df.shape[0]
start_time = time.time()
print(start_time)
data = {}


async def get_data(session, url, j):
    try:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            html = await resp.text()
            rawhtml = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
            title = rawhtml.title
            data[url] = {'url': url, 'resp': resp.status, 'title': str(title), 'html': str(rawhtml)}
            print(j)
            print(url)
    except Exception as e:
        data[url] = {'url': url, 'resp': str(e), 'title': 'None', 'html': 'None'}
        print(j)
        print(url)
        print(str(e))


async def get_queue():
    tasks = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout=aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=120)) as session:
        for j, i in enumerate(df.domain):
            i = 'http://' + i.lower()
            task = asyncio.create_task(get_data(session, i, j))
            tasks.append(task)
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(get_queue())

    with open('parsed_data.json', 'a+') as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(data))
    end_time = time.time() - start_time
    print(end_time)
```

Comment: This code is basically issuing all requests in parallel as fast as possible, before even the response to the first arrives. This should not be a problem if the requests are for different sites  - but if you are calling the same API or domain (you don't say that in the code, as the URLs are data and potentially with differing domains), you may be hitting an API limit, or DoS protection that is blocking you.

Comment: different sites

Comment: @jsbueno here is example of output data https://disk.yandex.ru/i/tUGweE2LCiCjVA. after 852 row only empty cells

Answer (score 0):

That was timeout error.

```
'resp': str(e)
```

This code prints only error exception message. TimeOut Error has no exception message, so str(e) = empty string.

str(repr(e)) helps to see an Error.